# Get page number from line number with synctex from command line

Tags: forward-inverse-search

I have several hundreds of line numbers in LaTeX file and I need to get corresponding page numbers on pdf. I would like to perform “command line” forward search, using some Synctex command line interface (that I don't want to develop).

Is there some way to get this using available synctex tools?

Cumbersome solution (without synctex): put `\refstepcounter{foo}\label{l-<linenumber>}` on each such line and get page number from aux file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
synctex -i linenumber:columnnumber:texfile -o pdffile
```

If I understood synctex correctly, the columnnumber is currently not used, i.e., it can be set to `1`.

This command might show multiple locations which could correspond to the line in the source code. (I would typically take the first one).